Troubleshooting: Unable to Connect to Database When Running on Mobile Phone, but Successful on Emulator
"I tried running a Flutter project on an emulator and managed to successfully connect to the database. However, when I attempted to run the Flutter project on a physical device, it failed to establish a connection with the database. I have tried various methods, such as altering ports and following tutorials from websites and YouTube, but to no avail.
Error output when running on the physical device:
"I/flutter (5535): Error during login: Exception: Error during login: ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.0.104, port = 41400, uri=http://192.168.0.104:8080/project/login.php"."
I attempted various troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue. Firstly, I modified the port settings to ensure compatibility with the physical device. Additionally, I followed online tutorials and guides from both websites and YouTube channels to troubleshoot database connection errors in Flutter projects.
I expected that by adjusting the port settings and following the provided tutorials, the Flutter project would successfully establish a connection with the database when run on the physical device. However, despite these efforts, the issue persisted. The error message "I/flutter (5535): Error during login: Exception: Error during login: ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out" continued to appear, indicating a connection timeout error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
